# Return a value given that a number is within a certain range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm looking for a little help on my scheduled withdrawals problem.  I currently solve this with nested IF functions, but I'm getting more and more ranges and that leads to more and more nested IF functions. On top of this I'm running optimization so at a certain point it just explodes.

The problem:

```
Low        High        Amount to withdraw
600000     2000000     32000
300000     599999      20000
0          299999      8000
```

So a user would enter in current storage, lets say 325000 and the sheet would spit out 20000. If a user submitted 153555 the answer would spit out 8000

Like I said with just 3 ratchets using nested if clauses isn't impossible, but there can be 10 ratchets and nested if clauses aren't feasible.  I'd like to solve this with Excel formulas and not a macro.

Answer (score 2):

Set up your bracket information in the following form<sup>1</sup>:

```
Low       Amount to withdraw
0         8000
300000    20000
600000    32000
2000000   #N/A
```

somewhere in your workbook; let’s say `E2:F5` (with headers in Row 1).  Then use the function

```
=VLOOKUP(value, E$2:F$5, 2)
```

to lookup and retrieve the second (i.e., Amount to withdraw) value in the last row in the table
where the `E` value (lower end of the bracket) is ≤ the lookup value; for example:

[image]

A slightly more realistic formula would be

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1), "", VLOOKUP(A1, E$2:F$5, 2))
```

which will display a blank result for a blank input (rather than treating it as 0).

---

<sup>1</sup> We don’t have the high ends of the ranges in the table because we don’t need to;
`299999` and `599999` are redundant when we have `300000` and `600000`.  We include `2000000`
as the low end of an undocumented bracket ranging from `2000000` to `∞`.

Comment: This would have to be tailored every so slightly to include the desired lookup, as the existing formula (E:F) only includes the low and high matching criteria rather than the returned "amount to withdraw". See: http://i.imgur.com/QULXJej.png

Comment: OK, oops; I left out some zeros. `30000` should have been `300000`, `60000` should have been `600000`, and `32500` should have been `325000`. If that’s what you’re saying, thanks for catching it, but, boy, you weren’t clear. And if that’s not what you’re saying, you’re not clear.

Comment: What are you talking about? I have the “Amount to withdraw” in Column F. I don’t have the high ends of the ranges in the table because I don’t need to; why would I need to have `299999` and `599999` in the table when I have `300000` and `600000`? In your example/illustration, Column D is not used. But also, it doesn’t help to illustrate your point if you’re using numbers you made up rather than the ones from the question.

Comment: I was misinterpreting your columns because of the missing 0s and lack of headers, but you are correct in the usage of just the "low" value. My argument was that you hadn't used the "high" values column, but I understand now that VLOOKUP matches for the closest value that is greater than or equal to. Thanks for helping me correct my own knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [index](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) and [match](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/funktion-vergleich-HP010062414.aspx?CTT=1) function.
<sup>Assuming you can sort your table ascended first. Or else `=MATCH()` doesn't work dorrectly</sup>

[image]

```
=IF(F2<=INDEX(A:C,MATCH(F2,A:A,1),2),INDEX(A:C,MATCH(F2,A:A,1),3),"invalid")
```

This also checks the higher value. I tweaked your table in row 3 for this scenario. Now,  400000 matches no valid range and shows *invalid*

#### Break down into small formulas in separate cells (user input is in cell F2)

```
[G9]  =MATCH(F2,A:A,1)             Find row in table
[G10] =INDEX(A:C,G9,2)             Find corresponding high value
[G11] =INDEX(A:C,G9,3)             Find corresponding amount to withdraw
[G12] =IF(F2<=G10,G11,"invalid")   Check if input is lower then upper boundary
```