# How to lookup a value within a range

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-excel

I need a formula to calculate values from slab Ranges.

for example

```
 columnA columnB
  1-10     A
 11-20     B
 21-30     C
 31-40     D
 41-50     E
 51-60     F
 61-70     G
 71-80     H
 81-90     I
 91-100    J 
101-110    K
111-120    L
```

Suppose the value in cell C1 is 15.  The answer in cell D1 would be 'B' because it falls in the 11-20 range in column A.

Comment: There is an easy way and a hard way.  The easy way is to modify Column A so that it contains just the left set of numbers.  If you really want to see the range as you have it displayed, put the right set of numbers in column B and move the current column B over.  That allows you to use a simple lookup described in this question: http://superuser.com/questions/842438/return-a-value-given-that-a-number-is-within-a-certain-range/842457#842457.  You could also leave column A as-is and add a helper column with just the left set of numbers.  Using column A as-is for the lookup would be convoluted.

Comment: Actually, it is even easier if you forget the starting ranges all together and just use the ending values. A1=10, A2=20, A3=30, etc.. The lower bound is always 1 higher then the upper bound of the previous line. It makes it much easier to adjust later. I'd just write a script for this though so ignore me.

Answer (score 0):

As fixer1234 writes, the simplest would be to change your column A to just be a single number (start of the slab range), and then use `VLOOKUP`.  But a formula that will work, leaving your data as is:

```
=LOOKUP(C1,--LEFT($A$2:$A$13,FIND("-",$A$2:$A$13)-1),$B$2:$B$13)
```

This assumes your slab ranges start in Row 2.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change a thing about your source data if you just use an array formula. This is the formula for `D1`. Note that it's an array formula so it has to be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
{=INDEX($B$1:$B$12,MATCH(C1,VALUE(LEFT($A$1:$A$12,FIND("-",$A$1:$A$12)-1))))}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your ranges like that, you might consider the following formula. Which goes into cell **D1**

```
=CHAR(65+INT((C1-1)/10))
```

As `=CHAR(65)` is equivalent to the character **"A"** and `=CHAR(66)` = **"B"**, the formula uses simple maths to arrive at the correct character, based on the value in cell **C1**.

Please note that this only works with your current setup. Ranges have equal width and lookup values in column **B** are concurrent (e.g. A, B, C, D,..etc)